# Why is 'Extended Iterable Unpacking' not working for empty strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

Why is

```
>>> a, *b = ''
```

not possible, when

```
>>> a, *b = ' '
>>> a, b
(' ', [])  # b == empty list here anyway.
```

and

```
>>> type('')
<class 'str'>
```

I mean, why isn't it

```
>>> a, *b = ''
>>> a, b  # a could == ''
('', [])
```

Comment: same difference as in: `a, *b = []` (empty list leads to the error) and `a, *b = [None]` (should work). It will fail for any empty sequence.

Comment: That makes an awful lot of sense, still I think I am just expecting it to be a little more pythonic. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is one *mandatory* variable specified.

The right side should have at least one item (one character for string).

---

According to [PEP-3131](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

> A tuple (or list) on the left side of a simple assignment (unpacking
>   is not defined for augmented assignment) may contain at most one
>   expression prepended with a single asterisk (which is henceforth
>   called a "starred" expression, **while the other expressions in the list
>   are called "mandatory"**). This designates a subexpression that will be
>   assigned a list of all items from the iterable being unpacked that are
>   not assigned to any of the mandatory expressions, or an empty list if
>   there are no such items.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) :

> The function `unpack_iterable()` in `ceval.c` is changed to handle the extended unpacking, via an argcntafter parameter. In the UNPACK_EX case, the function will do the following:

- collect all items for mandatory targets before the starred one
- collect all remaining items from the iterable in a list pop items for
- mandatory targets after the starred one from the list push the single
  items and the resized list on the stack

So it will failed in first step because there is no mandatory targets in your string.

For more info you can check `unpack_iterable` in `caval.c` :

```
unpack_iterable(PyObject *v, int argcnt, int argcntafter, PyObject **sp)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    Py_ssize_t ll = 0;
    PyObject *it;  /* iter(v) */
    PyObject *w;
    PyObject *l = NULL; /* variable list */

    assert(v != NULL);

    it = PyObject_GetIter(v);
    if (it == NULL)
        goto Error;

    for (; i < argcnt; i++) {
        w = PyIter_Next(it);
        if (w == NULL) {
            /* Iterator done, via error or exhaustion. */
            if (!PyErr_Occurred()) {
                if (argcntafter == -1) {
                    PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError,
                        "not enough values to unpack (expected %d, got %d)",
                        argcnt, i);
                }
                else {
                    PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError,
                        "not enough values to unpack "
                        "(expected at least %d, got %d)",
                        argcnt + argcntafter, i);
                }
            }
            goto Error;
        }
        *--sp = w;
    }

    if (argcntafter == -1) {
        /* We better have exhausted the iterator now. */
        w = PyIter_Next(it);
        if (w == NULL) {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                goto Error;
            Py_DECREF(it);
            return 1;
        }
        Py_DECREF(w);
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError,
            "too many values to unpack (expected %d)",
            argcnt);
        goto Error;
    }

    l = PySequence_List(it);
    if (l == NULL)
        goto Error;
    *--sp = l;
    i++;

    ll = PyList_GET_SIZE(l);
    if (ll < argcntafter) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError,
            "not enough values to unpack (expected at least %d, got %zd)",
            argcnt + argcntafter, argcnt + ll);
        goto Error;
    }

    /* Pop the "after-variable" args off the list. */
    for (j = argcntafter; j > 0; j--, i++) {
        *--sp = PyList_GET_ITEM(l, ll - j);
    }
    /* Resize the list. */
    Py_SIZE(l) = ll - argcntafter;
    Py_DECREF(it);
    return 1;

Error:
    for (; i > 0; i--, sp++)
        Py_DECREF(*sp);
    Py_XDECREF(it);
    return 0;
}
```